# Facebook, Twitter, Google+ graphics for free use

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

I'm creating login mechanisms that include login through Facebook, Twitter and Google/Google+.

Now all i need is artwork and graphics from these 3 different companies. I know i could have just googled myself a couple of "unofficial" images. But i thought i`d do it the proper way and go though official channels to obtain artwork and graphics that are licensed to be used by other websites.

Does anyone know where one can get a hold of the licensing details and artwork in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Twitter logos: https://twitter.com/about/resources/logos
- Facebook logos: https://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php